# What is the equivalent of string.makestrans() for lists or dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, translate

When using `string.makestrans()`, you create a translation table which works character by character.

For example, this translation table moves each letter over two place:

```
import string  

intab = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
outtab = "cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab"
translationtable = string.maketrans(intab, outtab)
```

What if I have a list of values which I need to translate?

```
intab = [`TBA', 'RIP', TGIF', 'FAQ']
outtab = ['To Be Announced', 'Rest In Peace', 
                     'Thank God It\'s Friday', 'Frequently Asked Questions']
```

What is the standard way to translate something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to create the pairs and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) to create the "translator" (dictionary):

```
intab = ['TBA', 'RIP', 'TGIF', 'FAQ']
outtab = ['To Be Announced', 'Rest In Peace', 
                     'Thank God It\'s Friday', 'Frequently Asked Questions']

translationtable = dict(zip(intab, outtab)) 
# {'TBA': 'To Be Announced', 'TGIF': "Thank God It's Friday", 'FAQ': 'Frequently Asked Questions', 'RIP': 'Rest In Peace'}
```